# Magento 2.1.8 Re-indexing Error

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm new to Magento and I am having a trouble with Re-indexing.

I have checked all of the questions with re-indexing problem but my problem is different.
My Cron job is showing the following error:

```
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

I have removed the memory_limit in php.ini, but it's still the same.

My Cron Job:

```
***** php /home/username/public_html/update/cron.php >> /home/username/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log
```

Can anyone help?[image]

The Following command: 
`* * * * * <path_to_php> <magento2_dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento2_dir>/var/log/update.cron.log`

is giving the ouput

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31 
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

But. My index aren't being reindexed. I'm using Cpanel.

Comment: have  you restarted your server after changing the limit ? or you can check the value from php info

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup proper **CRON** for your Magento2 Web Store:

to setup **CRON** you need to do following :

login via SSH to your server

edit cronjobs with this command

> crontab -e

after this a text editor displays. (You might need to choose a text editor first.)

here you need to add following lines ( make sure to change paths for your enviornment )

```
* * * * * <path_to_php> <magento2_dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento2_dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path_to_php> <magento2_dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento2_dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path_to_php> <magento2_dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento2_dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

here:

`<path_to_php>` is usually `/usr/bin/php` you can find this by command `which php`
if you have installed php-cli than you need to assign path for php-cli here

`<magento2_dir>` is the Root directory for Magento2 Installation.

Following is must have CRON for Magento2

```
bin/magento cron:run
```

Ex:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/username/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/update/cron.php >> /home/username/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/username/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

NOTE : IF you have **cPanel** or other Panels than you need to find **cron / scheduler** and setup the same there accordingly

Comment: Sorry, but You just re-posted my cron commands. That twhat Iasked forrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
I need to get the solution to the problem. The Following command:

 * * * * * <path_to_php> <magento2_dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento2_dir>/var/log/update.cron.log

is giving the ouput 

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

But. My index aren't being reindexed.
I'm using Cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact your server guy regarding that. They will increase the server memory limit. Or you can do on thing. First do the indexing using SSH and then try to set cron job. I hope it will help you.